# Silex Optional Route NotFoundHttpException

Tags: parameters, routes, silex, option-type

I'm having issue with a route in Silex.
I've already tried everything i've read on the web, but..i can't make it work.

Here is my code :

```
$getServer->get('/server/{cFM}&{name}&{tApp}&{active}.json', function ($cFM, $name, $tApp, $active) use ($app) {

if (!$server = Model\mdmServer::getServer($cFM, $name, $tApp, $active)) {  
  return $app->json('Not found', 404);
}
return $app->json($server);
});

return $getServer;
```

I'd like all my parameters to be optional, for example :

/server/cFM&&tApp&active.json

IF i don't put any value for name, i got the NotFoundHttpException.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define default values for the route parameters:

```
$app->get('/{pageName}', function ($pageName) {
  // ...
})
->value('pageName', 'index');
```

please have also a [look into the documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_term=Recent%20php%20Bookmarks%20on%20Delicious#default-values).

Comment: I've already tried this, it didn't work :/ , thanks for trying to help me btw !

Comment: Perhaps you have trouble because you are using an unusual route, try `/server/{cfm}/{name}/{tapp}/{active}` instead of `/server/{cFM}&{name}&{tApp}&{active}.json`

Comment: i've find a way to do it ! thanks for your help Ralf :)